# Java. Ошибка "error: cannot find symbol" в методе actionPerformed()

Tags: java, swing

Я новичок, разбираюсь с Swing. Почему при компиляции нижеприведенного кода возникает ошибка:

```
    TestGui.java:27:         error: cannot find symbol
                                System.out.println(field.getText());
                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable field
  location: class TestGui.FieldListener
1 error" ?
```

Пробовал аналогичные манипуляции с `JButton` (соответственно с другим методом в `ActionPerformed()`) - всё работает.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestGui {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        TestGui gui = new TestGui();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextField field = new JTextField();

        field.addActionListener(new FieldListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, field);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class FieldListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(field.getText());
        }
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что `field` является локальной переменной в методе `go()`, чтобы ошибки не было,  нужно его сделать полем класса

Answer (score 1):

FieldListener ничего не знает о вашей переменной JTextField field.
Вы можете сделать так:

```
class FieldListener implements ActionListener {
   private JTextField field;

   public FieldListener(JTextField field) {
      this.field = filed;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println(field.getText());
   }
}
```

И передать ваш field в качестве параметра конструктора.